# UIWebView dynamic content size

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I've been looking around and wasnt able to see any swift related ways to do this. I'm trying to get my UIWebViews height to be dynamic. I have a UIWebView that loads data using the loadHtmlString function.The thing is that I am loading the data from an sqlite database, each time I load a different string with different length and naturally the web view obtains different height.
Now I need to know how to make the UIWebView that exact height in order to load my next content right under the webView. This is what I have so far

```
var jobSkillView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(-5, 480.0, screenWidth, 300.0))
jobSkillView.loadHTMLString("<html><body p style='font-family:arial;font-size:16px;'>" + jobSkills + "</body></html>", baseURL: nil)
jobSkillView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.innerHTML")
jobSkillView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
jobSkillView.scrollView.bounces = true
jobSkillView.sizeToFit()
border.addSubview(jobSkillView)
```

I found something like this on SO but not sure how to link it to the `UIWebView`'s frame:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(jobSkillView : UIWebView){
    // Change the height dynamically of the UIWebView to match the html content
    var jobSkillViewFrame: CGRect = jobSkillView.frame
    jobSkillViewFrame.size.height = 1
    jobSkillView.frame = jobSkillViewFrame
    var fittingSize: CGSize = (jobSkillView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero))
    jobSkillViewFrame.size = fittingSize
    // webViewFrame.size.width = 276; Making sure that the webView doesn't get wider than 276 px
    jobSkillView.frame = jobSkillViewFrame
    var jobSkillViewHeight = jobSkillView.frame.size.height
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

*This post has been updated for Swift 5 & `WKWebView`*

---

So this is a really great function you wrote there, OP!
Here is just a shorter, more elegant version of your code:

```
// make sure to declare the delegate when creating your webView (add UIWebViewDelegate to class declaration as well)
myWebView.delegate = self

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
     webView.frame.size.height = 1
     webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
}
```

---

#### Migrating to `WKWebView`

1) import `WebKit`
2) make your `ViewController` inherit from `WKNavigationDelegate`
3) hook up the `WKWebView`’s delegate: `webView.navigationDelegate = self`
4) implement the following protocol function:

```
webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

After migrating from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`, above approach doesn’t seem to work anymore.
What you can do instead, is change the line with `webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)` to:

```
webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
```

The full code for `WKWebView` would then be:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
}
```

Comment: for iphone 5 and 5s the webView contentsize is not increasing

Comment: Are you sure you've followed the steps properly? Because for me it works on all devices equally.

Comment: yes i had as because for 6 and above its working fine

Comment: if possible can I get a sample for the same

Comment: in my case height of webview not increases if document body contains the image only

Comment: this makes my webview's height much shorter then it should be

Answer (score 20):

this only worked for me

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;
    myWebViewHeightConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
}
```

make sure you've created an outlet for myWebViewHeightConstraint

Comment: worked with me but i added updateConstrain at the end

Comment: @Gulz It is not working for UICollectionViewCell How to make it work for UICollectionViewCell

Comment: @AmalEl-galant I also updated constraint at the end, but it's width going beyond the screen. Height gets contracted but overlaps the views below itself

Comment: `WKWebView` has no member `scalesPageToFit`

Answer (score 6):

Here is my custom class to work with custom UIWebViews, it has everything in it to get the correct scrollview content height, set UIWebView height and create a custom height constraint to get autolayout working. It also loads some custom CSS styling...

```
class CustomUIWebView: UIWebView, UIWebViewDelegate {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
        self.scrollView.bounces = false
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
        self.scrollView.bounces = false
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func loadHTMLString(string: String!, baseURL: NSURL!) {
        var cssURL:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("webview", ofType: "css")!
        var s:String = "<html><head><title></title><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width\" /><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./webview.css\" ></link></head><body>"+string+"</body></html>";
        var url:NSURL

        if baseURL == nil {
            url = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL
        } else {
            url = baseURL
        }

        super.loadHTMLString(s, baseURL: url)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        self.webViewResizeToContent(webView)
    }

    func webViewResizeToContent(webView: UIWebView) {
        webView.layoutSubviews()

        // Set to smallest rect value
        var frame:CGRect = webView.frame
        frame.size.height = 1.0
        webView.frame = frame

        var height:CGFloat = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        println("UIWebView.height: \(height)")

        webView.setHeight(height: height)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: height)
        webView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        // Set layout flag
        webView.window?.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        webView.window?.setNeedsLayout()
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why isScrollEnabled is set to false.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using HTML string in my load and have to use the following method in Webview delegate:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
        self.webviewHeightConstraint?.constant = height as! CGFloat
    })
}
```

and the full code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webviewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
var observing = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    webview.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

        self.webview.loadHTMLString("""
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        ul {
        list-style: none;
        }

        ul li::before {
        content: "\\2022";
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1em;
        margin-left: -1em;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>Change Bullet Color of List Items</h2>

        <ul>
        <li>Adele</li>
        <li>Agnes</li>
        <li>Billy</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        </ul>

        </body>
        </html>
""", baseURL: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
        self.webviewHeightConstraint?.constant = height as! CGFloat
    })
}

}
```

Comment: Almost worked for me, however I was getting too way larger height than supposed to be.
Then I had to add this line into <head>:
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

See here: https://gist.github.com/pkuecuekyan/f70096218a6b969e0249427a7d324f91#gistcomment-2768462

Answer (score 4):

I had problem with:

```
let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
```

Sometimes my web view height simply didn't calculacte and stayed on default value. 
So finally I manage to find better solution that works fine, just replace that line code with:

```
let height = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.scrollHeight")
```

This is mine final complete code:

```
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    //webview height
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let height = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.scrollHeight")
    if let height = height {
        if let heightInt = Int(height) {
            let heightFloat = Float(heightInt)

            webViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(heightFloat)
        }
    }
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out what I was doing wrong so now I know how to call this function. First of all I was supposed to call a UIWebViewDelegate in my class. Then set my var jobSkillView to (jobSkillView.delegate = self). Now this is where I made my major mistake. In my code I had a if else statement that I was throwing my func webViewDidLoad in. I was supposed to put it out of that statement and into the actual class to override my frame for the UIWebView. Speaking of frame **** DONT FORGET TO SET YOUR FRAME HEIGHT TO 1. Then and only then this function will work for your UIWebView. After that you should have a fully functional based height for your UIWebView for Swift.

Comment: Can you please send the code. I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to make your UIWebView height dynamic in Swift 3.x

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {        

 let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
 var wRect = webView.frame
 wRect.size.height = height
 webView.frame = wRect

}
```

Comment: not working in UIcollectionViewCell @TejaKumarBethina , width going beyond screen and overlaps other views

Answer (score 1):

you can use this class for makking webview size to fit for swift 3 and swift 4

```
//
//  RSWebView.swift
//  CustumWebViewDemo
//
//  Created by Ruchin Somal on 01/01/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ruchin Somal. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class RSWebView: UIWebView, UIWebViewDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.scrollView.bounces = false
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.scrollView.bounces = false
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func loadHTMLString(_ string: String?, baseURL: URL?) {
        let s:String = "<html><head><title></title><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width\" /><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./webview.css\" ></link></head><body>"+string!+"</body></html>";
        var url:URL

        if baseURL == nil {
            url = Bundle.main.bundleURL
        } else {
            url = baseURL!
        }

        super.loadHTMLString(s, baseURL: url)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        self.webViewResizeToContent(webView: webView)
    }

    func webViewResizeToContent(webView: UIWebView) {
        webView.layoutSubviews()

        // Set to initial value of webview
        var frame:CGRect = webView.frame
        frame.size.height = 1.0
        webView.frame = frame

        // Calculated height of webview
        let wvheight: CGFloat = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        print("UIWebView.height: \(wvheight)")
        var wvRect = webView.frame
        wvRect.size.height = wvheight
        webView.frame = wvRect

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: wvheight)
        webView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        webView.window?.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        webView.window?.setNeedsLayout()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When font change at that time change `Webview` height to 1 than get proper `offsetHeight` for `Webview`

```
webView1.frame.size.height = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.frame.size.height = 1
        webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```