# How to set Viewcontroller dynamic height according to webview at its bottom?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

I have a view controller which has various components while a webview at its bottom everything is inside ScrollView but I ended up with double scroll one of main scrollview and one in the webview. How can I set the height of the main view to increase dynamically so that the webview would take its full height and I don't get a double scroll?
 I have tried something like this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

        myWebView.frame.size.height = 1
        myWebView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    }
```

from this answer :[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850792/uiwebview-content-height)

As suggested in the answer below I did this

```
mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mainScroll.contentSize.width, mainScroll.contentSize.height + webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

that increased the height of scrollview according to content size of webview but the height of UIWebview remaided the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Web view delegate method where it tells that loading has finished, you can do following

```
mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mainScroll.contentSize.width, mainScroll.contentSize.height + webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

I think this will work.

To increase the size of web view

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: sorry that my code is in objective c, but the logic will work in swift too.

Comment: yes this code increased the height of scrollview but the height of webview remained the same

Comment: i had done some changes in my answer, this will change the frame of web view.
If it worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer.