# UIWebView Dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want to add the dynamic height to `UIWebView` based on the content of the WebView.

I am loading the HTML file in my webView.

I have also referred to the following link.

[UIWebView dynamic content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850792/uiwebview-dynamic-content-size)

But didn't get the result.

Here is my code....

```
self.mapWebView.delegate = self
let mapHtmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "map", ofType: "html")
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: mapHtmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
self.mapWebView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
```

**Delegate method**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;
    self.cnDirectionWebViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true

   // tried following code. Doesn't work
   //webView.frame.size.height = 1
   //webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
}
```

Can anyone help me to get out this trouble?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: try this ?   webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=true;

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to achieve it using frames and not constraints. Replace your current implementation of `func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {}` with this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;
    let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.scalesPageToFit = false
    webView.frame.size.height = height
}
```

Using Constraints :

```
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
       webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false
       webView.scalesPageToFit = false
       self.cnDirectionWebViewHeight.constant = 
       webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
       webView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: It should work with frame. There may be an issue with constraints. But the frame one is bound to work

Comment: Did my answer with the frame work? the first code block

Comment: No I didn't try with frame...however, I am using storyboard. so don't want to use frame