# Change webview height based on html text using autolayot in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

created a webview which loads html text.

```
var html_string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."

self.webView.loadHTMLString(html_string, baseURL: nil)
```

i want set webview height to its content.without scrolling in the webView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIWebView dynamic content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850792/uiwebview-dynamic-content-size)

Answer (score 0):

Mind that the component is **WKWebView**, Webview is a thing of the past.

Try this function:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;
    myWebViewHeightConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
}
```

Remember to create an outlet for myWebViewHeightConstraint and updateConstrain as well.

You have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for this, I hope this helps you.

**Note:-** 'UIWebView' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: No longer supported, So please use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`

**For UIWebView**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled=false;
    myWebViewHeightConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
}
```

**For WKWebView**

If you want to use WKWebView then you need to do the following things.

1) import WebKit

2) make your ViewController inherit from WKNavigationDelegate

3) hook up the WKWebView’s delegate: webView.navigationDelegate = self

4) implement the following protocol function:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i am not getting full content height, i have mentioned webView height 200 in storyboard.

if the content height more than 200 it not increasing height but giving scrollable view

Comment: Hi @nshivaprasadreddy i think you have set fixed height 200 from storyboard, you need to update this, set height 0 or greater then constraint (height >= 0)

Comment: another option don't assign constraint just through auto resize