# How to calculate content height of WKWebView?

Tags: wkwebview

For UIWebView, we can get content height by this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"]
```

But WKWebView doesn't have this method and webView.scrollView.contentSize.height is not right.

```
(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
    {
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: WKWebView has - evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler: instead. It's asynchronous online UIWebView's method. You will need to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Do you find any solution for this issue ? Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the content size of a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview)

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem with KVO.

First, addObserver for WKWebView's scrollView's contentSize like this:

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "webView.scrollView.contentSize", options: .New, context: nil)
```

And next, receive the change like this:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "webView.scrollView.contentSize" {
        if let nsSize = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSValue {
            let height = nsSize.CGSizeValue().height
            // Do something here using content height.
        }
    }
}
```

It's easy to get webview's content height.

Don't forget to remove observer:

```
removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "webView.scrollView.contentSize", context: nil)
```

I worte this line in `deinit`.

Comment: webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "webView.scrollView.contentSize", options: .New, context: nil)


addObserver:<WKWebView.ViewController 0x7fd658433440> forKeyPath:@"webView.scrollView.contentSize" options:1 context:0x0] was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "webView" property.'

Comment: @orazz it will work only if your view controller (self) has property named `webView`.

Comment: I think this only works if the webView content is larger than the webView. if the content is smaller, you get the frame of the webView. Trying to figure out a good way to resize the webView to get proper sizes.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

To get the best possible height calculation, in the end I did a few things to get the best height:

1. I set the size of the webview to be really large and then load the content.
2. Once the content is loaded (KVO notification) I resize the view using the method below.
3. I then run the size function **again** and I get a new **size** and resize my view once again.

The above got the most accurate results for me.

**ORIGINAL:**

I've tried the scroll view KVO and I've tried evaluating javascript on the document, using `clientHeight`, `offsetHeight`, etc...

What worked for me eventually is: `document.body.scrollHeight`. Or use the `scrollHeight` of your top most element, e.g. a container `div`.

I listen to the `loading` WKWebview property changes using KVO:

```
[webview addObserver: self forKeyPath: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(loading)) options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: nil];
```

And then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object == self.webview && [keyPath isEqualToString: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(loading))]) {
        NSNumber *newValue = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        if(![newValue boolValue]) {
            [self updateWebviewFrame];
        }
    }
}
```

The `updateWebviewFrame` implementation:

```
[self.webview evaluateJavaScript: @"document.body.scrollHeight" completionHandler: ^(id response, NSError *error) {
     CGRect frame = self.webview.frame;
     frame.size.height = [response floatValue];
     self.webview.frame = frame;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this:

```
self.webview.navigationDelegate = self;

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webview didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
     // webview.scrollView.contentSize will equal {0,0} at this point so wait
     [self checkIfWKWebViewReallyDidFinishLoading];
}


- (void)checkIfWKWebViewReallyDidFinishLoading{
      _contentSize = _webview.scrollView.contentSize;
      if (_contentSize.height == 0){
           [self performSelector:@selector(WKWebViewDidFinishLoading) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[WKWebView didn't finish loading, when didFinishNavigation is called - Bug in WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291534/wkwebview-didnt-finish-loading-when-didfinishnavigation-is-called-bug-in-wkw/)
WKWebView doesn't use delegation to let you know when content loading is complete.
You can create a new thread to check the status of WKWebView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), {  
        while(self.webView?.loading == true){
            sleep(1)
        }            
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            print(self.webView!.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in a little more detail for it to be helpful to more people than just a copy -> paste -> "it works!" -> we're done here! - style.