# WKWebView not resizing when content changing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, wkwebview

WKWebView is not resizing when content changing.

Here is a code snippet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containingView: UIView!
var webView: WKWebView! 

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController();
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    self.webView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight]
    self.webView.loadHTMLString(__, baseURL: __))
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

    self.containingView.addSubview(self.webView)
}
```

What func should be added so I could intercept content size being changed and change the containingView size accordingly?

Comment: webview automatically scrolls so why do you need its height to change to content ?

Comment: I don't want it to be scrollable. I want the containing view to rescale according to the web content

Comment: you would need to use javascript to detect webview content height and set height manually

Answer (score 3):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("webview did enter did finish navigation")
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let heightOfContent = result as? CGFloat {

                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What halped me was to have small initial WKWebView height

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 150), configuration: configuration)
```

instead of

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), configuration: configuration)
```

Answer (score -4):

Conceptually in objective c you should do like below.

Two things:
Make sure to have these properties:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

And finally calculate webView content height as :-
`webView.isLoading` is one of the most important property. Actually in a single call to a web url it is called multiple times.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
if (webView.isLoading == NO)// as it is called multiple times so wait untill last call
{
 CGFloat height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
}

}
```

This is how you should compute web view height.

you can have a look here as WKWebView don't have a delete which you can use to get content size instead use KVO:

[KVO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291534/wkwebview-didnt-finish-loading-when-didfinishnavigation-is-called-bug-in-wkw)
May be it will help you more!

Comment: I am using WKWebView. It doesn't have scalesPageToFit property

Comment: But say I am changing my implementation to UIWebView, still there are some cases that webViewDidFinishLoad is not called even though content is changing on the screen

Comment: webViewDidFinishLoad ?? are you sure you have set delegate

Comment: it's WKWebView, not UIWebView