# WKWebView content height is way too big

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview, contentsize

I've tried all the answers for this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview) to calculate the correct content height of a WKWebView, but the result height is always beyond the actual height that makes a long empty area below the end of the content.

Ways I tried:

1. `webView.eveluateJavaScript()`
2. `webView.scrollView.contentSize`
3. `WKScriptMessageHandler (get the message.body.valueForKey("body"))`

And here's the HTML string I tried to load:

```
> <html><head><style>img{max-width:100%%;height:auto
> !important;width:auto !important;};</style></head><body
> style='margin:0; padding:0; font-size:[myFontSize];
> font-family:[myFont]; color:[myColor]'>[myHTMLstring]</body></html>
```

Is there another way to get the correct height of WKWebView?

Answer (score -1):

1. WKWebView, Set consistency with self.view.frame

2.Try it out,

```
<html>
 <head>
    <style>
       background-color:purple;
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

```