# Calculate html content height in UITextView failed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using a UITableView with custom Cell to render HTML code into an UITextView with AttributedString. The UITextView fit the cell and I am using Auto-Layout to get the dynamic height based on the content of the UITextView.

The html I use for the example is

```
<h1>hey this is a <a href="www.google.com">link</a><h1>
```

It seems that the height found is incorrect.

[image]

I also tried to determine the height of the content base on the string with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let text = content[indexPath.row]
    let tv = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bouds.width - 16 * 2, height: 1.0))
    tv.isScrollEnabled = false
    tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tv.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    let height = TextContentCell.calculateHeight(textView: tv, data: text).height
    return height
}
```

The calculateHeight function:

```
class func calculateHeight(textView:UITextView, data:String) -> CGRect {

    var newFrame:CGRect!
    do {
        let attr = try NSAttributedString(data: data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attr
    } catch {
        //Handle Exceptions
    }

    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    print("height \(newFrame.height)")
    return newFrame
}
```

This technique seems to return the exact same height that the dynamic height returned.

[image]

This problem occurs with html text no regular text.

[image]

Comment: you can try to remove all your `html tag` before calculate the height

Comment: Well a really good idea if this issue can’t be fixed in other way. Thank you for that

Comment: I think you can try to use WKWebView to load your html string, and then calculate height well. It supports the image, too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview

Comment: @QuocNguyen WKWebView is too heavy for a task like this

Comment: @QuocNguyen yes I first tried WKWebView but it seemed too heavy to use it in multiple UITableViewCell

Comment: @QuocNguyen for your idea to remove the html tag, if you have <h1>title</h1> that use a big font, if remove the html tags, you will have a smaller UITextView then the <h1> text height

Comment: @Florian_L  How about convert html to NSAttributedString? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886718/2776008

Comment: @QuocNguyen I already use this system to transform the html to an AttributedString, the problem is the height of the UITextView doesn't match the height of the text

Comment: @Florian_L seem like i found your problem. When you using <h1>, it auto add 2 newline char (\n) to your string, so your string is too long.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: @Aris iOS 11.4 on simulator and 11.4+ on real device

Comment: @QuocNguyen yes I also saw it while setting the UITextView isEditable to true (saw only one new line here)

Comment: @QuocNguyen but didn't find a good solution to remove this space without loosing the style of the AttributedString

Comment: @Florian_L I think that this is the correct behaviour since <h1> tags have bottom margin by default. If you remove the h1 tags the height will be what you expect

Comment: @Florian_L do you have any solution to resolve it so far?