# WKWebView: document.body.offsetHeight returns wrong height, why?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have this code:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.readyState" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable complete, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (complete != nil) {
            [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.offsetHeight" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable height, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                lastWebViewHeight = [height doubleValue];
```

Unfortunatelly for this HTML it returns 701px:

```
<html><head><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"></head><body bgcolor='#111111'>    <table width="100%">        <thead style="border: thin solid #000000; color: #fcfcfc; font-size: x-small; text-align: center;">            <tr>                <th rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap">                    FLIGHT NO.                </th>                <th rowspan="2">                    DATE                </th>                <th rowspan="2">                    FROM/TO                </th>                <th rowspan="2">                    PIC                </th>                <th colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap">                    FLIGHT TIME&nbsp;                </th>                <th colspan="3" nowrap="nowrap">                    BLOCK TIME                </th>                <th rowspan="2">                    TAKEOFF FUEL (KG)                </th>                <th rowspan="2">                    LANDING FUEL (KG)                </th>                <th rowspan="2">                    LDG                </th>            </tr>            <tr>                <th>                    T/O                </th>                <th>                    LNDG                </th>                <th>                    TOTAL                </th>                <th>                    OFF                </th>                <th>                    ON                </th>                <th>                    TOTAL                </th>            </tr>        </thead>        <tbody style="font-family: Arial; color: #4380EF;  font-weight: bold;            font-size: x-small;" align="center">                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    BBD299                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    22Dec18 06:30                </td>                <td>                    EGPH/EBLG                </td>                <td>                    CLD                </td>                <td>                    0640                </td>                <td>                    0753                </td>                <td>                    0113                </td>                <td>                    0625                </td>                <td>                    0756                </td>                <td>                    0131                </td>                <td>                    7400                </td>                <td>                    4400                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT010K                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    22Dec18 00:55                </td>                <td>                    EGSS/EGPH                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    0144                </td>                <td>                    0239                </td>                <td>                    0055                </td>                <td>                    0131                </td>                <td>                    0246                </td>                <td>                    0115                </td>                <td>                    7000                </td>                <td>                    4500                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT010J                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    21Dec18 22:25                </td>                <td>                    EGPH/EGSS                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    2236                </td>                <td>                    2335                </td>                <td>                    0059                </td>                <td>                    2222                </td>                <td>                    2358                </td>                <td>                    0136                </td>                <td>                    9700                </td>                <td>                    7200                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    004N                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    21Dec18 01:20                </td>                <td>                    EGNX/EGPH                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    0225                </td>                <td>                    0307                </td>                <td>                    0042                </td>                <td>                    0210                </td>                <td>                    0314                </td>                <td>                    0104                </td>                <td>                    7050                </td>                <td>                    5070                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT004S                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    20Dec18 23:30                </td>                <td>                    EGPH/EGNX                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    2343                </td>                <td>                    0028                </td>                <td>                    0045                </td>                <td>                    2333                </td>                <td>                    0032                </td>                <td>                    0059                </td>                <td>                    9000                </td>                <td>                    7250                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT004N                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    20Dec18 01:20                </td>                <td>                    EGNX/EGPH                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    0134                </td>                <td>                    0213                </td>                <td>                    0039                </td>                <td>                    0120                </td>                <td>                    0219                </td>                <td>                    0059                </td>                <td>                    6700                </td>                <td>                    4900                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT004S                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    19Dec18 23:30                </td>                <td>                    EGPH/EGNX                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    2341                </td>                <td>                    0026                </td>                <td>                    0045                </td>                <td>                    2330                </td>                <td>                    0030                </td>                <td>                    0100                </td>                <td>                    8800                </td>                <td>                    6900                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT004N                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    19Dec18 01:20                </td>                <td>                    EGNX/EGPH                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    0133                </td>                <td>                    0212                </td>                <td>                    0039                </td>                <td>                    0120                </td>                <td>                    0218                </td>                <td>                    0058                </td>                <td>                    6540                </td>                <td>                    4700                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT004S                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    18Dec18 23:30                </td>                <td>                    EGPH/EGNX                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    2347                </td>                <td>                    0034                </td>                <td>                    0047                </td>                <td>                    2335                </td>                <td>                    0039                </td>                <td>                    0104                </td>                <td>                    8800                </td>                <td>                    6740                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                        <tr style="color:#MISSINGPREFLIGHTCOLOR">                <td>                    NPT004N                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap">                    18Dec18 01:20                </td>                <td>                    EGNX/EGPH                </td>                <td>                    ROH                </td>                <td>                    0222                </td>                <td>                    0302                </td>                <td>                    0040                </td>                <td>                    0210                </td>                <td>                    0308                </td>                <td>                    0058                </td>                <td>                    6800                </td>                <td>                    4940                </td>                <td>                    1                </td>            </tr>                    </tbody>        <tbody style="border: thin solid #000000; color: #fcfcfc; font-size:small;">            <tr>                <td colspan="13">                    <hr />                </td>            </tr>            <tr>                <th colspan="4" style="color: Red;">                                    </th>                <th colspan="2">                    ACC. AIRBORNE TIME:                </th>                <th colspan="1" style="font-family: Arial; color: #HOURSOVERDUE#;">                    N/A                </th>                <th colspan="2">                </th>                <th colspan="1" style="font-family: Arial; color: #4380EF;">                </th>                <th colspan="2">                    ACC. LANDINGS:                </th>                <th colspan="1" style="font-family: Arial; color: #CYCLESOVERDUE#;">                    N/A                </th>            </tr>        </tbody>        <tbody style="font-family: Arial; color: #4380EF;  font-weight: bold;            font-size:small;" align="center">            <tr>                <td colspan="14">                    <hr />                </td>            </tr>            <tr>                <td colspan="5" align="center">                    SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE DUE AT:                </td>                <td align="right">                    HOURS                </td>                <td>                    N/A                </td>                <td colspan="2" align="right">                    DATE                </td>                <td nowrap="nowrap" style="color: #DATEOVERDUE#">                    N/A                </td>                <td colspan="2" align="right">                    LANDINGS                </td>                <td style="color: #LANDINGSOVERDUE#">                    N/A                </td>            </tr>        </tbody>    </table>    <table width="100%">       <thead style="border: thin solid #000000; color: #fcfcfc; font-size: x-small; text-align: center;">           <tr>        <th colspan="14" align="Center">        <hr/>        </th>      </tr>       <tr>        <th colspan="14" align="Center">        <SPAN STYLE="font-size: 12pt">The following is from the maintenance system "Gannet", and is info only.</SPAN>        </th>      </tr>            <tr>                <th colspan="14">                </th>            </tr>            <tr>                <th colspan="2">                    STATUS                </th>                <th colspan="2">                    WORK CARD NO.                </th>                <th colspan="4" align="left">                    TITLE                </th>                <th colspan="3">                    ITEM TYPE                </th>                <th colspan="3">                   DUE DATE / LIMIT                </th>            </tr>        </thead>        <tbody style="font-family: Arial; color: #4380EF;  font-weight: bold;            font-size: x-small;" align="center">            REPEAT2            <tr>                <td colspan="2" style="color: #STATUS#">                    [Status]                </td>                <td colspan="2">                    [WorkcardNr]                </td>                <td colspan="4" align="left" >                    [Title]                </td>                <td colspan="3">                    [ItemType] [MelItemNr]                </td>                <td colspan="3">                    [DueDate]                </td>            </tr>            REPEATEND2!            <tr><td colspan="13"></td></tr>        </tbody>    </table></body></html>
```

Though if I render it in a browser, browser requires much less `offsetHeight`. Do you have any idea why the difference?

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem , but not with UIWebView.
Any way, I think 
`- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {}`
doesn't exactly tell you when WKWebView finishes loading.

Comment: Hi @SkanderFathallah! Try to add this to HTML, it helped me. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Need to add meta tag as follows**

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width\" />
```

Comment: How to add the tag from Swift code?