# Height of TableView Cell is not changing dynamically according to WebView

Tags: swift, uitableview, wkwebview

I have used a `WKWebView` inside a `Tableview` cell, its `height` is not changing according to content inside webView.

If I directly load an `htmlString` inside webview, the height of the cell doesn't change even after calling `updateCellHeight()`.

This is my Custom Cell (the `urlString` is coming from an API call response so each time it will be different):

```
let cell1: NewCatDescrDCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! NewCatDescrDCell
  if !loaded { 
                cell1.urlString = "<p>Headers and Builders</p>"
                cell1.configure()
                cell1.tableView = tableView
             }

        loaded = true
        return cell1

     }
```

This is `NewCatDescrDCell` cell:

```
class NewCatDescrDCell: UITableViewCell, WKNavigationDelegate {

let webView = WKWebView()
var tableView: UITableView!
var heights : CGFloat = 1200.0
var heightconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var urlString: String = ""

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.addSubview(webView)

    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true


   }


func configure() {

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true    
    webView.loadHTMLString(urlString, baseURL: nil)    

    }

 @objc func updateCellHeight() {
    heights = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

    heightconstraint = webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heights)
    heightconstraint.isActive = true

    tableView.reloadData()
    }

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCellHeight), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

}
```

The `height` changes dynamically if I use an `url` to load inside `WebView`, but it is not working for `HTMLString`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue related to the WKWebView height on Stackoverflow.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
    if complete != nil {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
            self.containerHeight.constant = height as! CGFloat
        })
    }

    })}
```

try this or refer this on Stackoverflow
[How to determine the content size of a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview)