# How to get WKWebview content size in swift?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

i have a problem
get the WKWebview real content size, any ideas?

[How to determine the content size of a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview)
the answer above do NOT work for me, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below worked for me, but this maybe go wrong once WKWebview's view tree changes.
post your best answer, thanks!

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
        if let scroll_cls = NSClassFromString("WKChildScrollView"),
           let compose_cls = NSClassFromString("WKCompositingView") {
            let viewss = webView.allSubViewsOf(cls: scroll_cls)
            if let first = viewss.first?.subviews.first,
               first.isKind(of: compose_cls) {
                if webView.bounds.height >= first.bounds.height {
                    // webivew is at bottom
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


extension UIView {
    func allSubViewsOf(cls: AnyClass) -> [UIView] {
        var all = [UIView]()
        func getSubview(view: UIView) {
            if view.isKind(of: cls) {
                all.append(view)
            }
            guard view.subviews.count > 0 else { return }
            view.subviews.forEach{ getSubview(view: $0) }
        }
        getSubview(view: self)
        return all
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting your own question and answer, why not add your answer to the other question? But how does this code get the content size?