# UIWebView accessing photo library but with multiple selection

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I need help with this web wrapper app. In my app there is one UIWebView and it was working perfectly when I call input tag from UIWebView to access file and I haven't added any multiple in my code but still, the app is selecting multiple images but I want one image selection. please help me. here is my code.

```
[webPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
    [webPage setOpaque:NO];
    webPage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    webPage.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webPage.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webPage];
```

and i have simple `<input type="file" />`

Comment: anyone who can solve my problem??

Comment: share what HTMl and what you want , are you need to get all items between  `<input type= , />`

Comment: i have this simple tag in html <input type="file" /> for selecting olny one file/image from library but right now <input type="file" /> is letting user select multiple images but i want it to select just one image

Comment: its like this : <input type="file" name="policeRecord" id="policeRecord" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is UIWebView appends multiple attribute to HTML  tag automatically. 
This behaviour varies from iOS versions, I think this is a UIWebView's bug.

I had the same problem.Migrate to WKWebview from UIWebview, it's faster and will resolve this issue . Apple too recommends using WKWebview if app support is iOS 8.0 and above.

**iOS Code**

```
 // .h file
 // Please import #import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
    @property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;

// .m file in viewDidLoad Method
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
_webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y + 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
```

**Html used**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file"/> test single <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its worked but lil more help please tell me how to can i call webViewDidFinishLoad in WKWebVIew??

Comment: Yeah it is a bit different, For that you have to implement WKNavigationDelegate and this method is - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation; Please check these links also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate?language=objc

Comment: And also check this answer of stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504481/wkwebview-content-loaded-function-never-get-called/25508071?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I also observed such behavior using UIWebView. WKWebView works just fine.